# Having trouble opening an excel file (.xls) on a cell phone

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am creating an excel document in a web forms page and when I load that page I get prompted to download an excel file which opens up fine on my computer. 
But if I send the same file as an attachment and try to view it on my cell phone I get an error saying the file format not supported.

here is my code below.. hope someone can shed some light ....

The error I get on my phone says:

> File read error.  File type is unsupported or the file is corrupted.

excelling.aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="excelling.aspx.cs" Inherits="app_Files_excelling" %>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p runat="server" id="p1">Hello world.</p>
                <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>column 1 header</th>
                    <th>column 2 header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>column 1 value</td>
                    <td>column 2 value</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>Footer 1</td>
                    <td>Footer 2</td>

                </tr>

            </tfoot>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

excelling.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class app_Files_excelling : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=NCR.xls");

    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be HTML renamed as XLS.

Comment: In my code behind I do set Response.contentType to application/vnd.ms-excel.. i thought that would take care of it...

Comment: That's not XLS content. It's no wonder it can't be recognized. *I told my phone that my site was sending it an apple, but I sent a baseball instead, and it doesn't recognize that baseball as an apple. What's wrong?* You'd know the answer if you tried to make an apple pie using that baseball.:-) Setting the `response.contentType` to something does not magically convert content to a different type; it just tells the other end to expect the contentType you say you're sending. You still have to send the actual content in that contentType.

Comment: lol. so there is no workaround ?..

Comment: Yes. Send real XLS content, or change the contentType to HTML and rename the content *NCR.htm* or *NCR.html*.

Comment: when you say real XLS content.. what does that mean?... sorry if thats a stupid question.. does that mean i can not have <table>....</table> inside my doc?...

Answer (score 0):

Like those who have commented, you need to generate a real XSLX file before serving it via a browser. You can easily achieve that with many libraries.

[ClosedXML with Example](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Showcase)

[Serving the resulting file via ASP.NET](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Deliver-an-Excel-file-in-ASP.NET)